# Handshakes with different people

Tags: combinatorics

Jerry is shaking hands with a group of people. There are $n \geq 2$ people there. Any person can shake any number of the other peoples' hands, including zero, but any two people can only shake each other's hands once. Shaking hands is a mutual event between exactly two people.

Prove or disprove the claim that there must always be at least two people who shook the same number of hands as each other.

**I have two theories for this problem: this is a problem that involves the pigeonhole principle, with there being n-1 holes. Or that it is a problem that involves derangements. I am mainly not sure how to approach the problem.**

Answer (score 3):

Go with the pigeon hole proinciple. Each of the $n$ people will have shaken between $0$ and $n-1$ other peoples hands. If someone has shaken $n-1$ hands then they have shaken everyone elses hand & so there cannot be someone who has shaken $0$ hands.